# Replace the confirm javascript function with a jQuery dialog solution

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm novice with jQuery dialog and I'm looking for a way to replace to ugly **confirm javascript function** by a jQuery dialog. If possible I would like a solution as easy as possible to set in place.

Example:

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
      // user click Yes
}
```

To be replaced by a simple jQuery dialog solution. If possible an 'inline' solution like:

```
if jQconfirm("Are you sure") { ... }
```

I don't know if some solutions already exist?

Thanks.

Comment: It's already baked into the jQuery dialog codebase - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation - click on the _View Source_ on that page for the demo code, after closing the dialog :-)

Comment: Here is a demo of something that does form confirmation: http://www.jensbits.com/demos/forms/ Link to a tut is on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is complicated to have such an inline solution since the confirm() halts the execution of the script, however you may modify you script a bit and use such a construct:

```
$.confirm("message", "title", 
         function() { /* Ok action here*/
});
```

Check [this site](http://coding.abel.nu/2012/01/jquery-ui-replacement-for-alert/) for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

its the JqueryUI box, and works well in a model form